# openDocAsReadonly Computed?

Tags: javascript, xpages

I know there is the True/False option for this, but I'm wanting to have it differentiate depending on the status of a document. It only lets you select Edit or Read Only on the "Display" tab, but I'm thinking there has to be a way to compute this.

If the status of the document is "Sent" then I want it to open in Edit mode.

If the status of the document is "Reviewed" then I want it to open in Read Only mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit this property in "All Properties" tab

[image]

and write SSJS or EL code there.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see the blue diamond before, must have not scrolled far enough to the right. I don't really want to use expression language here, what would be the best way to write it in SSJS?

Comment: #{document1.status eq 'Reviewed'}

Comment: That doesn't work...   I was looking for something more like: if document1 status = "Reviewed" open in Read Only,  else open in Edit Mode

Comment: `openDocAsReadonly="#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue('Status') === 'Reviewed'}"` would work if you include a column "Status" into your view and set the viewPanel's `var=` property to "rowData".

Comment: You're right, I just didn't have my viewPanel set to rowData. Thanks Knut!

Answer (score 3):

Almost every control in XPages is really a bean meaning that you can compute almost all of its properties.

"*Why is it crucial to understand the nature of beans when developing XPages, even if you're not specifically writing Java code? Because darn near everything in an XPage is a bean.*"

Source: [What the heck is a bean?](http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-8GK6K7) by Tim Tripcony