# getComponent Code for openDocAsReadOnly

Tags: javascript, xpages

Is it possible to differentiate how documents open in a view on an XPage, depending on the status of a document using the `getComponent("programmaticname").getValue()` method?

If the status of the document is "Sent" then I want it to open in Edit mode. If the status of the document is "Reviewed" then I want it to open in Read Only mode.

I would like to compute the "openDocAsReadOnly" property in my view. Could someone show me what that code would look like?

[image]

Comment: *Never* use `getComponent("id").getValue()`... use `dataSource.getValue("propertyName")` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example:

```
<xp:viewPanel
    rows="30"
    id="viewPanel1"
    var="rowData">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:pager
            ...>
        </xp:pager>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView
            var="view1"
            viewName="yourView">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:viewColumn
        id="viewColumn2"
        displayAs="link"
        columnName="Reviewer"
        openDocAsReadonly="#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue('Status') === 'Responded'}">
    </xp:viewColumn>
```

It is important that

- viewPanel has `var="rowData"` so openDocAsReadonly can reference to current row with `rowData.`...
- view column Status has not only "Status" as title but as Programmatic use name too

  [image]

If all works fine then the URL of your Reviewer column should end with `&action=openDocument` if Status is "Responded" and `&action=editDocument` for all other cases.

Maybe the cause for you having trouble to get it to run is much easier: use for test "Responded", not "Reviewed". In your former [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21633159/2065611) you told Status is called "Reviewed", so answers use this. But, your picture here shows "Responded".

Comment: Okay, I had the wrong closing tags at the end of the openDocAsReadonly javascript code. I corrected that and it worked perfectly. Thank you Knut!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you define a variable name in your viewPanel at All Properties >> data >> var  (rowData is a frequently used variable name for that)

This variable holds an object of type NotesXspViewEntry, so it knows a method called .getColumnValue(colName:String), where colName is your Notes view column's programmatic name (I assume it's named "Status").

In consequence your openDocAsReadonly property could hold a code like this:

```
rowData.getColumnValue("Status")=="Responded"
```

**EDIT:**
sorry maybe made a mistake here; probably it doesn't work due to a wrong timing. Instead you could try to override the standard url link by defining it in the viewColumn's pageUrl property. A quick test revealed a code like this (I followed Knut Herrmann's observation):

```
var d = entry.getColumnValue("Status");
var a="editDocument";
if(d=="Responed") {
    a="openDocument"
}
"/yourDocXpage.xsp?documentId=" + entry.getUniversalID() + "&action=" + a
```

Not really sure though whether this is the best of all solutions...

Comment: I did this, they are all currently still opening in Edit mode.

Comment: I used the code that Knut listed and it worked great. I am going to try this one too though, just to see if there are any differences between the two once I get it plugged in. Thanks Lothar!

Comment: @Chad: Knut's version was my first approach as well, as you can see from my answer before the EDIT; so no real use to try this, it was just meant as a workaround in case the simpler solution hadn't worked